# Dynamically change href in last tab of jquery 'next/previous tab' controls

Tags: jquery, url, tabs

I use stackoverflow often so thanks to all who contribute - its been very helpful.

I am not an avid programmer and use jquery at its most basic level. I hope someone can help.

I would like to dynamically change the href url of '.nexttab' controls so that the user can move onto the next html page.

The below is my (juvenile) code.

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $(".nexttab").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");   
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);

        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var lasttab = $(this).ui.panel('id');
        if(lasttab == 'tabs-7'){
         $('.nexttab').attr('href', href.replace('#','http://google.com.au'));
        }
});
    $(".prevtab").click(function() {
        var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");   
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected - 1);
});

});
```

html is here

```
<div id="control-arrows">
<a href="#" class="prevtab control-arrow-left">< Back</a> | <a href="#" class="nexttab control-arrow-right">Continue ></a>
</div>
```

How can I identify the correct panel or tab (which is always the last) and then make the url change ?

Thank you,
Sarah